# Javascript array weird behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok, when write like below:

```
var element = { "name": "" };

var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    var newelement = element;
    newelement.name = i.toString();
    array[i] = newelement;
}
```

Result in:array[0].name == array[1].name == "1".
But write in another way:

```
var element = { "name": "" };

var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    var newelement = { "name": i.toString() };
    array[i] = newelement;
}
```

Result in:array[0].name == "0" and array[1].name == "1".

Tell me why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in the second example you are creating a new object on each iteration, but in the first example you are referencing always the same element.

Comment: Ehhhhhh how stupid i am... Since read some article about "Do not use new in javascript", every "=" is translated into "= new". Thank u for the answer anyway~

Comment: And json is one way to present OBJECT

Answer (score 2):

This is a good Javascript question for people to encounter and understand.

In the first block of code, you are assigning `newelement` a reference to `element`.  Each time through the loop, `newelement` gets the same reference assigned to it.  You aren't creating any new objects, just assigning the same one over and over again.

In the second block of code, you are creating a new object inside the loop so each assignment goes to a different object.

You need to remember that in javascript, assigning an object to a variable only assigns a reference to that object.

```
var newelement = element;   // just assigns a reference to an existing object
```

Yet, assigning like this is creating a new object:

```
var newelement = { "name": i.toString() };   // creates a new object
```

So, in the first code sample, you have `array[0]` and `array[1]` each with a reference to the same object.  When you modify that object, it affects both `array[0]` and `array[1]` since they are both pointing at that object.

In the second code sample, `array[0]` and `array[1]` are each pointing at a different object so when you modify one, it does not affect the other.

This is a tricky part of javascript and is something that often trips up C/C++ programmers (it certainly got me when I was first learning JS) who are use to something like the first assignment being a structure copy.  Javascript defaults to just assigning a reference unless you're using syntax that specifically creates a new object.